# Classes, Objects, and setter methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Trying to understand how to use `setter methods` Why am I getting a failure here? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please explain? Thanks.

```
class Book
  def title=(title)
    @title = title.capitalize
  end
end
```

**Rspec**

```
describe Book do  
  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end
  end
end
```

**Test Failure:**

> Book title should capitalize the first letter
>    Failure/Error: @book.title.should == "Inferno"
>
> NoMethodError:
>
> ```
>  undefined method `title' for #<Book:0x00000104abd538 @title="Inferno">
>  # ./ct.rb:865:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
@book.title.should == "Inferno"
```

you are essentially calling the `title` method on a `Book` object, which of course does not exist. You only defined the *setter*.

You also have to define the *getter*:

```
class Book
  def title
    @title
  end

  # ...
end
```

Note that there is a shorthand for defining both the setter and the getter:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
end
```

Comment: Yes makes sense. Question: Why doesn't this work? `@title = title.split.each { |w| w.capitalize }.join(" ")` Expected: "Stuart Little" but get: "stuart little". Why doesn't capitalize work here?

Comment: This is a total different question but here you go: `each` iterates over a collection but does not modify it. Use `map` instead: `@title = title.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')`

Comment: @Agis: Looks like you are hunting right with hunger.  Well done!